# Snowflake update value of all column with random value

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

There is a table Account_info.

```
Name   Email        salary
david  dv@some.com  10,0000
jimmy  jk@new.com   20,0000
....
```

I need to update the table such as it contains the data in scrambled
like

```
Name   Email        salary
xrfds  le@xxx.com   99,0000
aswss  ad@yry.com   11,0000
....
```

I tried to use row_generator but seems that wont help.

Any suggestion will help

Comment: Can you just obfuscate the column with Dynamic Data Masking?

Comment: Or you can use [RANDOM()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/random.html#random) and [RANDSTR()](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/randstr.html#randstr) functions.

Comment: Can you explain what kind of "scrambling" you want? If every single row needs to change its values to something random without any restriction, then why just not generate a new table with the same schema and number of rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `randstr()`, `random()` and `uniform()` and do something like this:

```
select randstr(5, random()) as name
     , lower(concat(randstr(2, random()), '@', randstr(3, random()), '.com')) as email
     , uniform(1000, 100000, random()) as salary;
```